# How to determine the next days of the week if I know the current day?

Tags: swift, calendar, nsdatecomponents

I created a weather application and for it I used API. (I used OpenWeatherMap and API as "Call 5 day / 3 hour forecast data")
I got all of the information that I need.

Then I got data for all days of the week. For example, Monday temp 22 degrees, Tuesday temp 12 degrees, and etc.

I can get the current day of the week and added to dictionary.

But I can't get new dayName (day of the week). What do I need to do?
I need help getting the names of the next days of the week and their indexes. And then add the key value to the dictionary.

```
// Indexed all days of the week Sun, Mon, Wed and a t.c             
let setWeekDay = IndexSet([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) 

//I detected current day of the weak and added to dictionary
var weakDay = [String:Int]()
let calendar = Calendar.current
var weekday =  calendar.component(.weekday, from: Date())
let components = DateComponents(weekday: weekday)

var dayName = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)?.Days()

weakDay = [dayName!:weekday]

if let nextWeekday = setWeekDay.integerGreaterThan(weekday) {
    weekday = nextWeekday
    } else {
        weekday = setWeekDay.first!
    }


...
// I extended date formatter
extension Date{
    func Days() -> String{
        let dataFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dataFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dataFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        return dataFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}

//This is dictionary will be change key and value dynamically.

//I need got dictionary as:
let weakDay = [
                "Sunday": 1,
                "Monday": 2,
                "Tuesday": 3,
                "Wednesday": 4,
                "Thursday": 5,
                "Friday": 6,
                "Saturday": 7,
                ]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please better explain what you need help with.

Comment: BTW - do not hardcode weekday names and numbers. The `Calendar` class provides the weekday names for you.

Comment: Hi and sorry for bad english!I need help getting the names of the next days of the week and their indexes.
And then add the key value to the dictionary.

Comment: I hope I could explain the problem more clearly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of the one for help, but i found answer on my question myself!
What i was need to be do:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "daysId", for: indexPath) as? DaysTVCell {

            var nameWeakAndIndex = [String:Int]()

            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.setValue(1, for: .day);
            var now = Date()

            for index in 0...5 {

                let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: now)

                let detectDayIndex = index

                nameWeakAndIndex = [now.Days():detectDayIndex]

                now = tomorrow!

                daysWeak.sort(by: { (nameWeakAndIndex[$0.dayOfTheWeak] ?? 6) > (nameWeakAndIndex[$1.dayOfTheWeak] ?? 6) })
            }


            let day = daysWeak[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(daysForecast: day)
            return cell
```